# How to use letsencrypt and prerender.io with meteor and nginx

Tags: meteor, nginx, prerender, lets-encrypt

There is scattered info, but no complete solution at one place. I am adding a working solution, which I am using at my production (with some security tweaks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Sample nginx.conf

```
# Upstreams
upstream index {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

# Servers
server {
  listen         80;
  server_name   example.com;
  location / {
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
  }
  location /.well-known {
    alias /var/www/example/.well-known;
  }
}

server {
  listen         443;     
  ssl        on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

  server_name   example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen         80;
  server_name   static.example.com;
  root          /static;
  expires 365d;

  # hide cookie header => cookie-free-domain
  fastcgi_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
  fastcgi_hide_header Set-Cookie;

  location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    expires     1M;
  }

  location /.well-known {
    alias /var/www/settlin/.well-known;
  }
}

server {
  listen         443;
  server_name   static.example.com;
  ssl        on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

  root          /static;
  expires 365d;

  # hide cookie header => cookie-free-domain
  fastcgi_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
  fastcgi_hide_header Set-Cookie;

  location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    expires     1M;
  }
}

server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  www.example.com;
  charset     UTF-8;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @prerender;
  }

  location @prerender {
    proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token aXwmLUBOhz9RqiuKnWUy;

    set $prerender 0;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }
    if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }

    #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    if ($prerender = 1) {
        #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
        set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
        rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
        proxy_pass http://$prerender;
    }
    if ($prerender = 0) {
      proxy_pass              http://index;
    }
    proxy_redirect          off;
    proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";
  }

  location /.well-known {
    alias /var/www/settlin/.well-known;
  }
}

server {
  listen         443;     
  ssl        on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  server_name  www.example.com;
  charset     UTF-8;

    location / {
    try_files $uri @prerender;
  }

  location @prerender {
    proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token aXwmLUBOhz9RqiuKnWUy;

    set $prerender 0;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }
    if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }

    #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    if ($prerender = 1) {
        #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
        set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
        rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
        proxy_pass http://$prerender;
    }
    if ($prerender = 0) {
      proxy_pass              http://index;
    }
    proxy_redirect          off;
    proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";
  }
}
```

Don't use this config yet, as the paths of certs do not exist. Just keep it handy.

### 2. Install `letsencrypt`

`sudo apt-get -y install letsencrypt` or the preferred way for your distro. Ref: https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/

### 3. Generate certificates:

Before doing this you will need the /.well-know location entries in your nginx conf, so that letsencrypt may verify the ACME.

`letsencrypt certonly --webroot -w /var/www/example -d example.com -d www.example.com -d static.example.com`

This command validates the certificates by accessing a key generated in `$webroot/.well-known/acme....` file. Which is why we ensure that the `.well-known` part is served directly through nginx, without going through meteor.

This will create the certs in /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com.

### 4. Auto renewal

First, a dry run to accept the terms.
`letsencrypt renew --dry-run --agree-tos`

Then a simple `letsencrypt renew` in crontab scheduled at 12 hours. The renewal is ideally needed only once a year, but a 12-hour check will guarantee that the certs are always up-to-date. If the cert is valid, then this command does nothing, and hence is safe.

### 5. Prerender

Since I am using nginx, it makes sense to handle prerender at nginx stage, instead of adding it to my meteor app.
The config simply says that every query will be internally redirected through a `@prerender` location, which will figure out if a prerender is needed or not. If required, then it will serve the request through service.prerender.io or else through meteor.

### NOTE:

`static.example.com` code in nginx conf is purely optional. I personally prefer nginx to serve the static files. This way I can also ensure that the static file serving domain is cookie-free.

### References:

1. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04
2. https://github.com/prerender/prerender
3. https://gist.github.com/thoop/8165802